# Objectbox fetching from db is showing out of date information

Tags: android, kotlin, objectbox

I have been using object box seamlessly for 3 years. I modified one of my objects by adding an extra parameter called "public" which is a boolean value. When I store the object in the db the value is true. When I fetch the object from the db it is false

```
    private fun storeChannelsInDb(channels: List<Models.Channel>) {
    channels.forEach { channel ->
        val channelMapped = ChannelMapper.toObjectBoxModel(channel)
        channelBox.box.put(channelMapped)
        if(channelMapped.channel_id == 7 ){
            println("********* storing "+ channelMapped.public)
        }
    }
}

override fun getChannels(): List<Channel> {
    for (channel in channelBox.box.all){
        if(channel.channel_id == 7){
            println("********* fetching  "+ channel.public)
        }
    }
    return channelBox.box.all
}
```

[image]

I don't provide a default value for this parameter as it is always returned from the api. I fetch these objects on launch of the app and empty the box before adding them.

I've tried adding delays etc but always returning false. Even when I provide a default value of true it is returning false. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: "public" might be a problematic name. Can you try another one? Also, is there any chance that the generated code became stale (is not updated)?

Comment: ah that was it!! public was a protected word. Annoying there was no error to display this. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was "public" being a protected word. Changing the name solved the issue thanks to the comment from @user:551269

Comment: FYI the related GitHub issue with more details: https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/879

Comment: ah thank you! this is a very useful link in that GitHub issue https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html